# Javascript regexp group info maybe miss sometimes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging

I write a regex with named group, ant tested it ok on the console of Chrome dev tools, but When I add it to my script and run, the group info missed.

The worked test code like this

```
const contents = `; the is some comment
name1           IN  CNAME   value1
name2           IN  A   value2
;name3          IN  A   value3
; the is another comment
name4           IN  A   value4`

const regexp = /(?:^;\s*(?<comment>.+?)\s*$\n)?^\s*(?!;)(?<name>.*?)\s+(?<className>.*?)\s+(?<type>.*?)\s+(?<value>.*?)$/gm

const matches = contents.matchAll(regexp)
for (const match of matches) {
  console.info(match)
}
```

and the following was the snapshot of Chrome dev.

[image]

That's really strange, When I debug it, it always have the group name info, but missed when it run in a script.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. When I run your script and `debugger` it, `regexp` appears to include all groups (on Chrome 76), it's not changed from the definition. Or were you expecting the `console.info` to result in something else?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, Hi, my question is that If I run the same code in my script, the `console.info(\`regexp\`, regexp)` show no group info.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out the issue, it was because I used babel in my project, the regexp in my project was wrapped via babel plugin (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex), and the version of it was old and may contain this kind of bug.

I could fix this problem with updating the dependences via `yarn upgrade` or `ncu -u && yarn`. Hope someone else who have the same issue could get help from this post.